# TestFlight Beta Testing update available email contains old app name

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

My app is in the development process and I used to send build to the client for testing using TestFlight Beta Testing. All internal testers receive an email from TestFlight that app is available for testing. Email subject line is like this : "TestFlight: There is an update available for AppName 1.0 (1.1)"

Recently our app name has changed. I did update app name at all possible locations in the app also and on the iTunes also. And whenever I upload the build now for testing, the email from TestFlight still contains old app name in the subject line. Where did i missed to update the app name?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have done everything correctly so I think this is going to simply be a **bug**.

But is that actually a critical bug? I bet if you submit the app to the AppStore the name will be the one you set the latest.

Hope that helps :)